# Berkeley DB: "make install" fails on Linux

Tags: linux, berkeley-db

I am trying to install Berkeley DB 18.1.40 (C++ version) on my virtual machine (Linux-Ubuntu).

When I do `sudo make install`, I encounter the following error messages:

```
Installing DB include files: /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/include ...
Installing DB library: /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib ...
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/libdb-18.1.so /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib/libdb-18.1.so
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/libdb-18.1.lai /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib/libdb-18.1.la
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/libdb-18.1.a /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib/libdb-18.1.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib/libdb-18.1.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib/libdb-18.1.a
libtool: install: cp -p libdb.a /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib/libdb.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib/libdb.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib/libdb.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Installing DB utilities: /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin ...
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_archive /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_archive
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_checkpoint /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_checkpoint
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_convert /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_convert
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_deadlock /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_deadlock
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_dump /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_dump
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_hotbackup /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_hotbackup
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_load /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_load
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_log_verify /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_log_verify
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_printlog /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_printlog
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_recover /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_recover
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_replicate /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_replicate
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_stat /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_stat
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_tuner /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_tuner
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_upgrade /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_upgrade
libtool: install: cp -p .libs/db_verify /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/bin/db_verify
Installing documentation: /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.18.1/docs ...
cp: cannot stat 'bdb-sql': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'gsg_db_server': No such file or directory
Makefile:1307: recipe for target 'install_docs' failed
make: *** [install_docs] Error 1
```

I am quite confused of why it is prompting this error, as `bdb-sql` and `gsg_db_server` is not something that is mentioned in the installation manual.

Does anyone know how these errors can be fixed?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I am also having this issue, which may be more an administration issue that a development issue.  One approach may be to build the missing components by adding configure flags, downgrading, or modifying the source to fix this obvious bug with libdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @fuzzyTew said, this appears to be a bug with 18.1.40, but as it's limited to the documentation it should be safe enough to patch yourself. There's two simple ways to do this. By far the easier is to just create the directories it wants in the `docs` directory, easily accomplished with `mkdir db-18.1.40/docs/bdb-sql db-18.1.40/docs/gsg_db_server`. This will leave you with a random pair of empty directories in your documentation folder, but I can't find any references even within the documentation itself that uses them so it should be safe enough. Alternatively, you can remove them from the Makefile after running `configure` using `sed -i.bak -e 's: bdb-sql : :' -e 's: gsg_db_server : :' Makefile`. Personally, I prefer just making the empty directories as it's nearly impossible for that to go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answers, I found that the best solution for me was to copy the missing directories from 18.1.32 into my 18.1.40 source:

```
tar -xzvf db-18.1.32.tar.gz
tar -xzvf db-18.1.40.tar.gz
cp -rp db-18.1.32/docs/bdb-sql db-18.1.40/docs/
cp -rp db-18.1.32/docs/gsg_db_server db-18.1.40/docs/
```

This way you get the best of both worlds... you don't have to downgrade to 32, and you get the docs instead of empty doc folders. Obviously, these docs are for the previous version and might not be 100% correct, but IMO they are better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with libdb 18.1.40 and should be reported to Oracle.  Version 18.1.32 is at https://download.oracle.com/otn/berkeley-db/db-18.1.32.tar.gz